# Mount a file instead of directory using sshfs?

Tags: mount, ssh, sshfs, fuse

Is it possible to mount a single file instead of a whole directory using sshfs command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not possible. Only filesystems can be mounted.

Comment: other solution: I created symlinks to all files I needed in a directory and then mounted that directory.